# Array push with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push an error message to a field if it is invalid.
this code works

```
let message = [];
if (!isvalid) {
        message.push("Please enter a value");
 }
```

How can I achieve this with ternary operator.
The way I did.

```
message.push((!isvalid) ? "Please enter a value" : null)
```

But this code is also pushing null to the array.
like:: message=[null]

Comment: what is the value of isValid ?

Comment: what you need in place of null ? you can also add blank string like "" in place of null, else you are using in right way

Comment: valid is true initially. And I want to push the message only when the valid is false else dont push anything.

Comment: Why do you want to use a ternary operator when you don't really have an else condition?

Comment: It does not make sense for you to use a ternary here. If you were trying to decide between two vales to push, then a ternary would make sense. But in your case, you are trying to decide whether or not to push to the array. This is the perfect use case for an if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, it's not a good way to do it. It does not make sense to use a ternary where one logical branch of the condition leads to ...do nothing. Ternary only makes sense where you want to *return* one of two values depending on the condition.

If you want to be concise you could use:

`!isValid && message.push('foo');`

though some linters won't like you for it. It has the disadvantage that it is less readable than a simple if. If you must use the ternary, you *could* also do this:

`!isValid ? message.push('Please enter a value') : void 0; // or null`

but it's ugly and bad because of that useless hanging `false` branch of the ternary expression. Don't do it.

Comment: do you mean this is not a good way to do it or what?

```
!isValid && message.push('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `(!isvalid) ? message.push("Please enter a value") : null` ?